# Can't receive emails from Wordpress after adding user

Tags: wordpress, gmail, wordpress-admin

I tried adding a user with Gmail ID and also tried with other email ids too but didn't get any confirmation email after doing so.

Please let me know what I need to do in order to receive corresponding emails after registering a user in WordPress admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working on localhost or server?
If you are working on localhost then you can setup the SMTP on xampp or wampp or whatever you are using.

If you are working on server then you need to contact with service provider.

Thanks